# Getting previous values from windows.print() in javascript

Tags: javascript

### The Problem:

When ever I choose the print button then this code will work and pop up for print appears  after choosing print it's working fine.

The problem is, if I choose the Cancel button of windows print option and if I'm going to print a new page then it is showing the *cancelled* page, not the **new** one.

---

[image: Print Screen Screenshot]

### Question

> Is there any option to clear or remove what I write in this line         `win.document.write(inf);`?

**Code**

Here is the code, it will always show `haiiiiii` in print preview can't update that text field.

### Script:

```
function displayMessage(printContent) {     
    var inf = printContent;
    document.innerHTML="";
    win = window.open('about:blank');
    win.document.write(inf);
    win.print();
    win.close();
    alert(inf);
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <div id="printadform">
            <table width="997" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" bgcolor="#999999"><div align="center" class="style1"><input type ="text" value="haiiiiiii"/></div></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
 
<a class="btn btn-primary" id = "print" onclick="displayMessage(formdiv.innerHTML)">Print</a>
<a href="#/branch/list/{{student.branch}}" class="btn" id="cancel">Cancel </a></div>
```

Comment: What is **printContent** in your document?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit  it is content from web page

Comment: why this question has 2 close votes any suggestions please.. I hav a serious issue in my application

Comment: @Parvathy  `formdiv.innerHTML` is the content for `inf` on clicking the print link. element with id `formdiv` changes dynamically?

Comment: @bios no form div is not changing. the content is same. next time i again enter new values then the formDiv will change. but it is not changing after clicking print.

Comment: @Parvathy check and update this **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/oRuyOMU/1/edit)**

Comment: @bios check that link, i updated for static value itz ok bcz it will be same , but dynamic value itz always printing first value

Comment: @Parvathy I've updated it with a **add** button that will add content dynamically do check.**[Link](http://jsbin.com/oRuyOMU/9/edit)**

Comment: @bios i gav a sample code there plz check that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41178/discussion-between-parvathy-and-bios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Text elements don't have an `innerHTML` property so you have to set the value filed.

Html:

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
        <div id="printadform">
            <table style="width:80%;border: 1px solid black;">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#999;">
                        <span style="text-align:center;">
                            <input id="box" type="text" value="Hai" />
                        </span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function displayMessage() {    
    var val = box.value; //get the input box value
    box.setAttribute('value', val); //set value attribute into input
    var inf = formdiv.innerHTML;
    document.innerHTML = "";
    var win = window.open('about:blank');
    win.document.write(inf);
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oRuyOMU/11/edit)**</kbd>